# Angularjs ng-show on ng-click not working

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I have created a button like with angularjs,

```
 <button class="btn btn-setting" ng-click="showSearch = ! showSearch" > 
  <img src="theme/images/settings.png" width="111">
 </button>
```

And a div like ,

```
<div  ng-include="'pages/include/search.html'" ng-show="showSearch" ></div>
```

I need to toggle the visibility of the above div on the button click.but it is not showing.

Comment: What about `showSearch` ? Have you declared it false before ?

Comment: Post entire code (HTML) what you posted is fine.

Comment: Can you show a bigger part of your html? Are they sharing the same controller? Can you bind some other value? Is your app and template loading correct?

Comment: created plunker http://plnkr.co/edit/sP3sZY2neTmnMa74o7vL  seems to be working fine there.

Comment: Do one of these , **$scope.showSearch = false or ng-init='showSearch=false'**

Comment: actually both of these elements in my index.html.is this make problem?i am new in angular js

Comment: any console errors ?

Comment: @K.Toress console was clean

Comment: If you ignore ng-show, does your ng-include work at all?

Comment: @Patrick yes,The div is showing

Answer (score 1):

Update the **showSearch** model as follows

```
$scope.showSearch = {hideShowSearch : false}
```

Updated HTML

```
<button class="btn btn-setting" ng-click="showSearch.hideShowSearch = ! showSearch.hideShowSearch" > 
  <img src="theme/images/settings.png" width="111">
 </button>

 <div  ng-show="showSearch.hideShowSearch" >This is the test</div>
```

EDIT -

In your script  **hideShowSearch** is primitive one.So it does not perform two way data-binding.As result you not getting expected result.

Answer (score 0):

Just do

```
<button ng-click="setshowme(show)"></button>

$scope.setshowme = function (value) {
    if(value == true){
      $scope.show = false;
    }else{
      $scope.show = true
    }
}
```

Comment: if you set up local variable as $scope.show you can check it inside of function instead pass untrusted entry value throw value aka setshowme() and inside function if($scope.show) { ...

Comment: true that just copied it from my example where i pass a second parameter =)

Comment: This doesn't change anything with the original question. Having a function call instead of just doing `show = !show` is pretty much equivalent.

Comment: well if u do it like that u need an ng-init which defined the value at load else its just undefined

Answer (score 0):

Here is a [simple JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/michelem09/0tey5qL3/)

```
<button class="btn btn-setting" ng-init="showSearch = true" ng-click="showSearch = (showSearch) ? false : true;" > 
    <img src="theme/images/settings.png" width="111" />
</button>

<div ng-show="showSearch">Hello World</div>
```

Comment: good .. but IMHO write js in html is ugly if is not necessary

Comment: I did what he asked, converting it to use a controller it's really easy

Comment: Why are you using the ternary operator instead of just toggling the value by inverting it with `!`?

Answer (score 0):

First check these two elements (`<button>` & `<div>`) inside two `ng-controllers`

If so this will not work since `ng-controller`s have their own `scopes`. So that `showSearch` is in one scope and other controller scope do not have direct access to it.

Then check something like,

```
<div ng-show='showSearch'>show / hide div ...</div>
```

and see if this div is toggling its visibility.

if it working properly

then check the path to `src` of `ng-include` is correct.

here is a [DEMO](http://plnkr.co/edit/oJMA1ceCHV0jRwXPclAU?p=preview)